# How do I reset Twitter access permission on iPhone Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, acaccount

The title is the question. NOTE: This question is limited to the iOS Simulator - things work better on the device.

I'm building a client that accesses Twitter via a Twitter account on the iPhone. The first thing it does is ask for permission to accounts, via the `requestAccessToAccountsWithType:options:completion:` method of ACAccountStore. The completion handler selects the account if there is only one and allows the user to choose an account when more than one. Further, it presents an alert about limited functionality if access is denied.

I'm trying to verify the completion handler for that method, particularly the part where access is denied, but I'm having no joy in that endeavor.

My first thought was to check in Settings > Privacy > Twitter. No apps are listed (even though my app is actually accessing the account), so I can't modify it there. I've tried Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy but no joy there either. There does not seem to be a menu item for this either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a hardcore way of resetting, but if the other methods you've tried don't work, then this should. Go to iOS Simulator->Reset Content and Settings...

[image: How to reset Content and Settings]

Comment: Good news and bad news. The reset allowed me to test the "No twitter accounts case," but I still can't test the "Access denied" case in the simulator. Looks like I have to rely on on-device testing for that...

Comment: Yes, this seems like one of those situations a development device is required for. Only when using a device can you properly simulate a user experience!